# winform modify height in form load event

Tags: c#, winforms, height

I want to resize my WinForm in **`Form_load`** event.
 I wrote the line

```
this.Height -= 100;
```

in the `Form_load` event but it does not work, how can I achieve this?

```
private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          //somecode

          if (m_HideControls)
          {
               // do some controls visible to false
               this.Height -= 100;
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: This should work,nothing wrong in this. post more code

Comment: where you subscribed form load event?

Comment: yes, you are right, it was because of minimum size property :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your Forms Windowstate is set to **Normal** and the new size doesn't violate the Forms Min/Max size, this should work just fine..

Answer (score 0):

Setting "Autosize" property to False for Form did the trick for me.